# ForeignKey save data with form crispy

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views, foreign-keys, django-crispy-forms

Hi I have those two models and I have ForeignKey field related to 1st model.

```
 class WELLMod(models.Model):
    WellID    = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
    Perimetre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    post_date   = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author      = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.WellID
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('WellDt', args=[self.pk])
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-post_date',)


class DSTMod(models.Model):
    WellID    = models.ForeignKey(WELLMod ,to_field='WellID', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    TotalDpt      = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    post_date   = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author      = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.WellID_id
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('WellDt', args=[self.WellID_id.pk])
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-post_date',)
```

#formes.py

```
class WELLForm(forms.ModelForm):
    WellID = forms.CharField(label='Well ID',max_length=15)
    Perimetre = forms.ChoiceField(label='Perimetre',max_length=15,required =False)
    class Meta:
        model= WELLMod
        fields=['WellID','Perimetre']

class DSTMForm(forms.ModelForm):
    WellID_id = forms.CharField(label='Well Name',max_length=15)
    TotalDpt  = forms.CharField(label='Total Depth(m)',max_length=15,required =False)
    class Meta:
        model= DSTMod
        fields=['WellID','TotalDpt']
```

## Views.py

```
class PostCreateWell(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView): 
    model = WELLMod
    template_name = 'Home/WELLINFO/Add_well.html'
    form_class = WELLForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostCreateDST(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = DSTMod
    template_name = 'Home/WELLINFO/WellDST/Add_DST.html'
    form_class = WELLForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

## url.py

```
path('Add_well/', views.PostCreateWell.as_view(), name='NEWWELL'),
path('Add_Dst/', views.PostCreateDST.as_view(), name='WellDST'),
```

And My template is

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <!-- form  from views.py-->
<div class="border p-2 mb-3 mt-3 border-secondary">
    <h3>Drill Stem Test</h3>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">{{ form.WellID|as_crispy_field }}</div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">{{ form.TotalDpt|as_crispy_field }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
    <input class="btn btn-success mb-4" type="submit" value="ADD WELL">
</form>
```

the probleme is when I add a well it works good but when adding DSTMOD it doesn't save my data and turn the the same page with no error? why and how I solve this?
N.B whene I use the admin tool to add data it works good.

Comment: I'd made the changes in forms.py
    class Meta:
        model= DSTMod
        fields=['WellID_id','TotalDpt']

in template
{{ form.WellID_id|as_crispy_field }} it save data but not WellID_id and it is empty ???

Answer (score 0):

the solution of save data is made by changing these:

```
class DSTMForm(forms.ModelForm):
    WellID_id    = forms.CharField(label='Well Name',max_length=15)
    TotalDpt      = forms.CharField(label='Total Depth(m)',max_length=15,required =False)
    DSTr      = forms.CharField(label='DST Result', widget = forms.Textarea(),required =False)
    class Meta:
        model= DSTMod
        fields=['WellID_id','TotalDpt']



<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <!-- form  from views.py-->
    <div class="border p-2 mb-3 mt-3 border-secondary">
        <h3>Drill Stem Test</h3>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">{{ form.WellID_id|as_crispy_field }}</div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">{{ form.TotalDpt|as_crispy_field }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <input class="btn btn-success mb-4" type="submit" value="ADD WELL">
</form>
```

but another problem, that when I save data it save all other fields except the first field

and it is empty!!??? and I don't know why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get the answer
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

I had added forms.ModelChoiceField and its queryset.

```
class DSTMForm(forms.ModelForm):
    WellID    = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Well Name',queryset=Wellinfo.objects.all())
    TotalDpt  = forms.CharField(label='Total Depth(m)',max_length=15,required =False)
    DSTr      = forms.CharField(label='DST Result', widget = forms.Textarea(),required =False)
    class Meta:
        model= DSTMod
        fields=['WellID','TotalDpt']


<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <!-- form  from views.py-->
    <div class="border p-2 mb-3 mt-3 border-secondary">
        <h3>Drill Stem Test</h3>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">{{ form.WellID|as_crispy_field }}</div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">{{ form.TotalDpt|as_crispy_field }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <input class="btn btn-success mb-4" type="submit" value="ADD WELL">
</form>
```